# Google Drive client/server app

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I would like to have a client app on Android that takes user input and associated data, zips it up, and stores the data on the user's Google Drive account.  Then the client app would share the zip file with the server's Google Drive account.

The .net server would be monitoring its account for new zip files that it then processes to another file and shares with the original user.  The server would then send the user an email notifying him that the results are stored on his Drive.

Is this workflow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow is possible in many ways, but you don't need a Google Drive account for the server.

Your authentication should let the server knows about the user's credentials. Then, your server can make a server side request to retrieve the files, process them and upload the processed files to user's Drive.

Comment: Wow.  I will look into this.  Any more details or pointers you can share?

Comment: What exactly would the user's credentials consist of that would need to be shared with the server?

Comment: Authenticate user on the server side by implementing OAuth2 flow and store an access token on the session. You either can proxify all Google Drive API requests on the client or share the access token in a secure way with the client.

Comment: Let me see if I can interpret what you are saying.  Let us take the Android DriveQuickstart as an example.  In the MainActivity an object of type GoogleAccountCredential is instantiated.  This object has a method getToken() that returns a String.  Is this what my Android client app would pass to the server?

Comment: Now that I reread your comment you are suggesting that the user be authenticated on the server side.  I would need to have my app do that and pass the access token to the server.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, I have implemented the .NET Quickstart and modified it to do a file listing.  That program requires an authorization code to complete the request.  It works fine when I use the code provided by the program.  I also created a drive file listing app for android and intercepted the authorization token there.  I tried using this token as the authorization code for the .NET app and it comes back with an error.  I am not surprised that it is not so simple.  Burcu can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: After further study it seems like implementing Server-side Authorization might work.  My Android app would have to acquire an authorization code that it would pass to the server which would in turn exchange it for an access token.  However, it seems like the Android Drive SDK returns the access token directly.  Is it possible to get an authorization code on the Android side that can be passed to the server?

Comment: It's possible, go to https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android, `GoogleAccountCredential` has a method called `getAccessToken` which will return you one.

Comment: I believe you are talking about getToken(), which appears to return an access token and not an authorization code that can be shared with the server.  Am I wrong?